# Upgrading Evolution from source

Tags: 11.04, bash, evolution, install-from-source

As with most people I presume I am running Evolution 2.32.2 inside 11.04 Natty and regardless how annoying the crashes are I prefer it to Thunderbird.

Obviously as soon as 11.10 Oneiric is released Evolution is being dropped which isnt too much of a problem as I intend to re-install it anyway.

Now to my question...

I want to upgrade Evolution to the latest version (3.0.02).
I downloaded the Tar.bz2 file and a [MAKEFILE](http://mad-scientist.us/Makefile) script created by Paul Smith.

The script checks for Evolutions dependencies along with some Phyton files. I downloaded all of these using *sudo apt-get install* (this took me ages) and continued to run the Makefile which simply hangs.

The Tar does come with an install-sh script which for the life of me I can not run in terminal as SH is not a valid command.

I have ./configure which tells me there is a problem with intltool being out of date which it isnt

Can someone take me through the process of installing from source in Ubuntu or tell me an easier way to update Evolution.

I have checked the depository and 2.32.2 is, according to the list, a current version

Comment: I'm not positive, but doesn't Evolution 3.0.x require Gtk 3?  If that's the case, building from source is almost certainly not worth the headache.  I'd just wait for October, if I were you. :)

Comment: gtk-doc-tools is a pre-requisite which has been installed yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are also looking for alternative solution for installing...

There are a couple of developers on Launchpad who have created an installable Evolution v3.0 via a PPA for Natty

[Alessio Igor Bogani](https://launchpad.net/~abogani/+archive/e3natty) looks promising.

Also

[Данило Шеган](https://launchpad.net/~danilo/+archive/evolution) has a package also available if you are using the gnome-3 ppa as well.

Note - as with all PPAs, they may eat your computer and/or your emails!  Have a good backup first.  Its also worth install ppa_purge to revert your evolution install if things dont go as you expect.

Comment: I thank you for this. Added ppa:abogani/e3natty to the package manager clicked upgrade and away we went.Such an easy solution for a problem that has been cursing me for days!

Answer (score 2):

Evolution is not the easiest piece of software to deal with because of dependencies of other parts of GNOME. I would recommend that you join the evolution mailinglist and join their IRC channel. There are many helpful people both places and my experience is that these issues are very difficult to solve in the kind of one-shot answers that this site is designed for.

Mailinglist: http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/evolution-list
IRC channel: #Evolution on irc.gimp.org